# How to make h1 text below navigation

Tags: html, css

I am new to learning html. I have a problem with putting h1 below nav!

I'm learning watching tutorials on youtube and is currently stuck in this phase of nav (wrapper).
    Really appreciate if someone could help!

```html
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul
    </nav>
    <h1>Test.</h1>
        </div>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please close your `ul` tag properly.

```html
<html>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h1>Test.</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! haha, didn't notice that! Appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The h1 tag was below nav when I ran your code but I did notice that your  tag is not closed properly. Maybe that's the cause of your error. replace `</ul` with `</ul>` and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check your  and then check if you still have the error. BTW please check your code before asking a question.